# What is Coding in Vacuum?

Tags: coding-style, terminology

What does the term "Coding in Vacuum" mean? I have heard the term before but I am unable to find anything on Google that is relevant.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System

Comment: [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) is a version control system.

Comment: My first thought was of [Clean Room Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design), but I think @Jess's answer is better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I interpret this as a derogatory comment about someone writing software while not considering the greater context of the project.  For example:

> "Didn't Bob know that this email client was supposed to handle emails
>   with images?"
>
> "I guess not, I think he was just coding in a vacuum."

Answer (score 3):

I like this answer from the English Usage StackExchange:

https://english.stackexchange.com/a/46270